IPython Seems to Be Installed But Won't Run
It seems to me that iPython is already installed because when I install it I am getting "Requirement already satisfied"... messages. However, when I go to launch it by typing ipython I get the following:
> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable Requirement already satisfied: ipython in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (8.23.0) Requirement
> already satisfied: decorator in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (5.1.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.16 in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (0.19.1)
> Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib-inline in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (0.1.6)
> Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=3.0.41 in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (3.0.43)
> Requirement already satisfied: pygments>=2.4.0 in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (2.17.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: stack-data in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (0.6.3)
> Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=5.13.0 in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (5.14.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (4.11.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3 in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from ipython) (4.9.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: parso<0.9.0,>=0.8.3 in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from
> jedi>=0.16->ipython) (0.8.4) Requirement already satisfied:
> ptyprocess>=0.5 in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages
> (from pexpect>4.3->ipython) (0.7.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> wcwidth in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from
> prompt-toolkit<3.1.0,>=3.0.41->ipython) (0.2.13) Requirement already
> satisfied: executing>=1.2.0 in
> ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from
> stack-data->ipython) (2.0.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> asttokens>=2.1.0 in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages
> (from stack-data->ipython) (2.4.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> pure-eval in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from
> stack-data->ipython) (0.2.2) Requirement already satisfied:
> six>=1.12.0 in ./Library/Python/3.11/lib/python/site-packages (from
> asttokens>=2.1.0->stack-data->ipython) (1.16.0) heather@C02H55GGQ05F ~
> % ipython zsh: command not found: ipython

What am I missing friends? Thanks in advance!

Is the bin directory for the environment you're installing into in your PATH?

Does python3.11 -m IPython work?

Or to moot that, use python -m ipython, with the same python that your pip linked to. (If you're not sure, use python -m pip and python -m ipython -- that way you know they're both referring to the same interpreter).

Well, you get a pretty clear error message: There is no executable named ipython in your PATH (and also no alias or function of this name in your shell). So, first check your installation by running the command with an explicitly specified PATH, and if this works, fix your PATH.

@wim that did the trick, unfortunately I don't see a check box next to your answer to be able to accept it. Since python3.11 -m IPython worked, do I still need to add anything to my path?

@Heats  It is not an answer, it is a workaround. I will add an answer describing what you need to do in this case.

Since using python3.11 -m IPython works, it means the user installation was successful in your python3.11 runtime. However, for the ipython command to work, the scripts path (where the ipython executable should be found) needs to be present on the $PATH environment variable.
The location of the scripts path is platform-dependent, but can be found within Python using:
import sysconfig
print(sysconfig.get_path("scripts"))

Append this location to the $PATH var with something like this in your shell:
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH   
# linux/macOS.
# use "set" instead of "export" for windows.

You may also want to append the path in your shell init files, e.g. in ~/.zshrc.

Thanks! I did run the script you sent and got the following output:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin
I tried setting the absolute path - my account is sitting at /Users/heather
export PATH=/home/heather/.local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin:$PATH
heather@C02H55GGQ05F ~ % ipython
zsh: command not found: ipython

@Heats What is your OS/platform?  What does python3.11 -m sysconfig | grep userbase show?

Wim! Thanks for not giving up on me! I have Ventura 13.6
userbase = "/Users/heather/Library/Python/3.11"

@Heats  Then try and export PATH=$PATH:/Users/heather/Library/Python/3.11/bin.

Can I just add this directly to my zshrc?

Yep, as mentioned in the last line of the answer.
